# Prolog, Printing variable instead of actual answer, works for different answer but not for duplicates

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-toplevel

```
singleShiftDataGen([Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4],Shifts, 
      PersonData1,PersonData2,PersonData3,PersonData4):-
   find(Name1, Shifts, PersonData1),
   find(Name2, Shifts, PersonData2),
   find(Name3, Shifts, PersonData3),
   find(Name4, Shifts, PersonData4).
%checkSingleShiftReport(PersonData1,PersonData2, PersonData3,PersonData4).

% This method will take in one single.       
find(Item, [[Item|T1]|T2], T1).
find(Item, [[_|_]|T], List):-
   find(Item, T, List1),
   append([], List1, List).
```

Input:-

```
singleShiftDataGen([young, collins, vieira, liu], [
[aziz, 1, 0, 0],
[blumenthal, 0, 1, 1],
[collins, 1, 1, 1],
[davis, 1, 0, 0],
[ericson, 1, 0, 0],
[fitzgerald, 1, 0, 1],
[gutierrez, 1, 0, 1],
[hughes, 1, 0, 0],
[jones, 1, 1, 1],
[kelly, 0, 1, 1],
[liu, 1, 0, 1],
[martinez, 0, 1, 1],
[patel, 1, 1, 1],
[qureshi, 1, 1, 0],
[rodriguez, 1, 0, 0],
[singh, 0, 1, 1],
[tortorella, 0, 0, 1],
[williams, 1, 0, 0],
[vieira, 0, 1, 0],
[young, 0, 1, 0],
[zimmerman, 1, 1, 1]], Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4).
```

Actual Output:-

```
Person1:- Person3
Person2:- [1, 1, 1]
Person3:- [0, 1, 0]
Person4:- [1, 0, 1]
```

Expected Output:-

```
Person1:- [0, 1, 0]
Person2:- [1, 1, 1]
Person3:- [0, 1, 0]
Person4:- [1, 0, 1]
```

As you can see I am getting the output which is Person1 = Person3 instead of actual integers in a list. Is there a way I can fix that? because of that my whole homework assignment won't work.

Comment: `append([], List1, List).` is the same as `List1 = List`

Comment: So, what should I do, copy whatever in List1 in to List, instead of appending it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your code is working. `Person1 = Person3` it's just a feature of the SWI-Prolog console interface (so called toplevel). I guess the UX choice inspiring the behaviour is to make easier to detect when Variables being reported are equals for *complex* values.

*edit*

Seems the feature cannot be disabled, but you can inspect a variable - after a successful query - with the $VARIABLE syntax (available only in toplevel):

```
?- write($Person1).
[0,1,0]
Person1 = [0, 1, 0].
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.